# Open Multiple Windows via PHP

Tags: php

fairly simple question and I haven't seen anything asked with this exact scenario laid out.

I have a form on a page. "Page 1"
The form's action is calling a PHP document, and the target is set to _blank. "Page 2"
The PHP document processes the information, then sets the header info to a specific page. "Action 1"

---

I would like for "Action 1" to instead open multiple pages; I know of several ways to do this via javascript, however, I would like to stay entirely within the PHP file if at all possible.

Comment: PHP is a server side language and cannot give commands to the browser like this. You have to do it client side, like with Javascript.

Comment: PHP doesn't have any control over the browser. You'll have to use Javascript. You can make your PHP output the appropriate Javascript.

Comment: Sure you can do it in PHP, just have the PHP output JavaScript. :)

Comment: `echo "<script src="some.js" />"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As php is a server-side language and HTTP has (thankfully) no way of redirecting to *multiple* URLs, you'll need to implement your [feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/01/922449.aspx) in JavaScript. Note that this is extremely likely to fail on mobile and exotic user agents, and it's a hassle to users in any case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to open multiple pages, however it's not really nice. You can do that with frames and always leaving one frame as the next target which will be a new frameset leaving one frame as the next target and so on.

Done that you can continue to open new frames - until the last one is about the size less a pixel on the target screen. This does only work if the browser still supports frames.